# Radius of convergence in power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Given the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2^n}$$
>   determine the radius of convergence, and what can we say when $x=R$ and $-R$?

1. Is it a power series? Power series should have the form of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
   but the given series does not match this form.  If not a power series, why can we say about its radius of convergence?
2. By the ratio test, I get that this series converges when $|x|<1$, diverges when $|x|>1$, so $R=1$, is that right?
3. When $x=1$ or $-1$, series both becomes $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n,$$
   then obviously, series diverges. Right?

Comment: It is a power series because $a_n = 0$ when n isn't a power

Comment: $\sum \left(-1\right)^n x^{2^n} = x - x^2 + x^4 - x^8 + x^{16} - \cdots$, so this is clearly a power series. Just plug in some $0\cdot x^n$ terms for the powers of $x$ that do not appear explicitly

Comment: About 3., you are right, except that when $x=-1$, the sum is $-1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$. The first term is the only one with odd power of $x$, so its sign doesn't follow the rest of the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1): see the comments.

(2): the radius of convergence  $\rho$ of $\sum a_nx^n$ is defined to be:

$$ \rho:=\frac{1}{\alpha} $$

where

$$ \alpha = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} $$.

Here we have:

$|a_n| = 1$ if $n$ is a power of 2, $|a_n|=0$ otherwise. Thus $\rho=1$.

Comment: Actually, numbers $2^n$ are not normally what we call "square numbers".  But the argument is still OK using "power of two" instead.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, edited!